# Scikit-Learn pipeline code difference between ColumnTransformer and FeatureUnion

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm using Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow: Concepts, Tools ...
By Aurélien Géron.

I'm trying to run the code in chapter 1 After "Transformation Pipelines" and before "Select and Train a Model".

The old version of book used the following code to do a combined transformation:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator , TransformerMixin
class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,  attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values

from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
#from sklearn_features.transformers import DataFrameSelector

num_attribs = list(housing_num) 
cat_attribs = ["ocean_proximity"]


num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(num_attribs)),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ])
cat_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('selector', DataFrameSelector(cat_attribs)),
    ('label_binarizer', LabelBinarizer()),
    ])

full_pipeline = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
    ("num_pipeline", num_pipeline),
    ("cat_pipeline", cat_pipeline),
    ])

housing_prepared=full_pipeline.fit_transform( housing  )
housing_prepared
```

The new code, however, used the newly introduced ColumnTransformer

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
num_attribs=list(housing_num)
cat_attribs=["ocean_proximity"]

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(),cat_attribs),
    ])
    housing_prepared=full_pipeline.fit_transform( housing  )
    housing_prepared
```

I'd like to know why the old versions of code was discontinued and not working, and what's new of ColumnTransformer compare to FeatureUnion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [featureUnion vs columnTransformer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604249/featureunion-vs-columntransformer)

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance, what I see is that they used a `DataFrameSelector` to select which columns to further process in the pipeline. This was pretty cumbersome because you always had to define that `DataFrameSelector` by hand. This is the problem that `ColumnTransofmer` solves.

I don't think that the first way "stopped working", it's just that having the second option, you should try to use that instead. Your code snippets are a nice example of how this new feature helps to write clearer code.

Hope this clarifies your doubts!

Answer (score 1):

A new alternative to this approach, which you may find simpler, is the new `skdag` package (disclaimer: I am the author). I wrote this because personally I found ColumnTransformers and FeatureUnions to be hard work, and Pipeline's support for Pandas dataframes wasn't enough for me.

`skdag` should support everything you're trying to do natively without any need for custom classes to handle dataframes. It lets you build up your workflow as a graph so there's no need for FeatureUnions any more. Here's your example rewritten with `skdag`:

```
from skdag import DAGBuilder

dag = (
    DAGBuilder(infer_dataframe=True)
    .add_step("input", "passthrough")
    .add_step("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median"), deps={"input": num_attribs})
    .add_step("attribs_adder", CombinedAttributesAdder(), deps=["imputer"])
    .add_step("std_scaler", StandardScaler(), deps=["attribs_adder"])
    .add_step("label_binarizer", LabelBinarizer(), deps={"input": cat_attribs})
    .add_step("merged", "passthrough", deps=["std_scaler", "label_binarizer"])
    .make_dag()
)

dag.fit_transform(housing)
```

If you want to visualise the graph, you can call `dag.show()` in an interactive environment like Jupyter Notebooks, or dag.draw() to produce an image or text file:

```
dag.show()
```

[image: dag]

Full documentation can be found at https://skdag.readthedocs.io/.

Answer (score 0):

`ColumnTransformer` is a better choice than `FeatureUnion` for data preprocessing step as it is more simple and we need to write less code.